# Unable to lock file in python

Tags: python, mutex

I have written two scripts in python that will be working with data in the same directory. One script will be set to run every 5 minutes and will save data to the directory, and then once a day the other script will zip all of that data, archive it and delete the original files. To avoid the archiving script deleting files which may be being saved by the worker script, I want to create a system-wide mutex so that the worker script knows not to run while the archiver is doing its thing.

I've done some searching and seen that on unix-based systems, the generally accepted method of doing this is to attempt to lock a file. If you get the lock then great, go ahead and run, if you can't get it then you know the other process is already running. I've written the following code:

```
import fcntl
import traceback

class ProcessLock:

    def __init__(self, path_to_file, block):
        self.file_path = path_to_file
        try:
            options = fcntl.LOCK_EX
            if not block:
                options = options | fcntl.LOCK_NB

            self.file = open(path_to_file, 'w+')
            self.lock = fcntl.flock(file, options)
        except:
            print 'caught something: {}'.format(traceback.format_exc())
            self.file = None
            self.lock = None

    def is_locked(self):
        return self.lock is not None

    def unlock(self):
        self.lock = None
        self.file = None

def aquire_lock(lock_name):
    path = '/tmp/{}.lock'.format(lock_name)
    return ProcessLock(path, False)

def aquire_lock_blocking(lock_name):
    path = '/tmp/{}.lock'.format(lock_name)
    return ProcessLock(path, True)
```

However for the life of me I can't get it to actually work. I have searched and all of the samples I've seen and other questions posted on here seem to work using the code that I have got. I've also tried both `flock` and `lockf`, but neither work. The call to `open` works correctly, but I get the following logged out to the console:

```
self.lock = fcntl.flock(file, options)
TypeError: descriptor 'fileno' of 'file' object needs an argument
```

I don't know enough about Python to be able to know what this error means. Hopefully someone can see if I'm doing anything wrong. I'm running this in Pycharm on macOS

Comment: Note: A better solution is probably not to bother with locks, but to make a parallel directory (on the same file system) that you write the new files to, close the files (`flush` and `os.fsync` first if you want to be super careful), then use an atomic rename (e.g. `os.rename`) to move the file from the temp directory to the "gold" directory. Similarly, the archiver would scan the directory for names up front and store the names found, zip only those names, and delete only those names (so if a new file appeared while archiving, it wouldn't be deleted). Together, no locks are needed.

Comment: The advantage to this solution is that doesn't involve complicated coordination between processes; the writer just writes in a safe way, the archiver reads in a safe snapshotting based way, and it's impossible for one (or more) writers to block the archiver indefinitely if they are constantly writing.

Comment: File locks make sense when equivalent processes compete for a resource. In your case, only one side will ever want to lock the directory. So just have it create a sentinel file before it starts work, and remove it when it's done. The other side checks for the existence of the file. Refinement: Write the pid of the archiving process in the sentinent file. The worker process can then check that the archiving process still exists (and didn't terminate abnormally without removing the lock.)